# file uploader PHP doesn't work, I don't know why

Tags: php, upload, file-upload, is-uploaded-file

**My HTML FORM code:**

```
        <form action="upload.php" method="GET" enctyped="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="file"> Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="loadedFile" id="file"/></br>
            <input type="submit" name="uploadItNow" value="Submit"/>
            hai, this is this the uploader.
        </form>
```

**PHP File uploader script:**

```
if (isset($_GET['uploadItNow'])) // checks if submit button has pressed
{

    if ($_FILES['loadedFile']["error"] > 0)

        echo "Error: ". $_FILES["loadedFile"] ["error"]. "</br>";


    else
    {
        echo "Upload: ". $_FILES["loadedFile"] ["name"]. "</br>";
        echo "Type: ". $_FILES["loadedFile"] ["type"] . "</br>";
        echo "Stored in: " .$_FILES["loadedFile"] ["tmp_name"];
        echo "Size: ". ($_FILES["loadedFile"] ["size"] / 1024). " Kb</br>";

        //Copies file from TEMP_PHP dir to d.default dir
        if (file_exists("." . $_FILES["loadedFile"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["loadedFile"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }

        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["loadedFile"]["tmp_name"],"." . $_FILES["loadedFile"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["loadedFile"]["name"];
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason it doesn't work, my scrip keeps going to this code:

```
echo $_FILES["loadedFile"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
```

Comment: Try changing "enctyped" in your form tag to "enctype"

Comment: Have you considered that the file exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use POST as well as change "enctyped" to "enctype".

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for fast a fast repley!

Answer (score 3):

Try to change form method to POST

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using POST instead of GET

Maybe the file really does exist? And you're not thinking about the paths

Answer (score 1):

Change method to post and enctyped to enctype

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```